# Does the Rust compiler convert String to &str implicitly?

Tags: rust

I implemented the trait `Foo` for `&'a str`, but when I call the method `test` for `std::string::String`, it works. I checked my code and I'm sure that I don't implement the trait for `String`, so does the Rust compiler convert `String` to `str` implicitly?

The code likes this:

```
pub trait Foo {
    fn test(self) -> String;
}

impl<'a> Foo for &'a str {
    fn test(self) -> String {
        String::from("da")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("123456789");
    println!("{}", s.test());
}
```

The Rust plugin for the Jetbrains IDE can't find `test` method for `String`, but it works well.

Why does that code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, careful. `String` != `CString`. And `s.test(var)` will not yield anything but an error since your `test` method takes no parameter but `self`.

Now, on to what is *actually* happening.

When you define an extension method like you did by defining a trait then implementing it for `&_ str` but not on `String`, and then try to invoke it, the compiler implicitly does the dereferencing (since `String` implements `Deref` into `&_ str`).

As a result, your `main` function can be written for clarity as:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("123456789");
    println!("{}", (s.deref()).test());
}
```

and is entirely analogous to what the compiler does under-the-hood. The compiler essentially saw that you were trying to use this, and did so for you.

I need to warn you, though - your code is extremely weird in multiple ways:

- One normally implements trait methods like these on objects, not their `Deref` counterpart, precisely to avoid this level of indirection
- Your implementation consumes a reference. Consider this for a moment.

A much better, and less indirect way to write it, is as follows:

```
pub trait Foo {
    fn test(&self) -> String;
}

impl Foo for str {
    fn test(&self) -> String {
        String::from("da")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("123456789");
    println!("{}", s.test());
}
```

You are not sacrificing anything, the functionality remains identical, but:

- You are no longer needlessly consuming a reference
- You are no longer needlessly forcing the compiler to infer a `deref` call

Comment: I just edit my sample code, actually I want to use `Foo` trait like this `"some word".test()`, and I just wonder why `String` works too.

Comment: @McGrady as stated in the reply - the compiler is taking advantage that `String` implements `Deref` into `&'a str`, doing the call to `deref()` for you, and then using your method. Two years ago, this would've been an error.

Comment: @trentcl Good catch. Seeing as the method in the trait is no longer requiring `self` but `&self` instead, there is no reason for `Foo` to be on `String` as opposed to `str`. Editing.